# SQL Max and Sum

Tags: sql

Below is my query that I am using:

```
SELECT 
   County,
   Code,
   Sum(PaidAmount) AS TotalPaid
FROM
   Counties
GROUP BY
   County,
   Code
```

It returns the set:

```
County     Code         TotalPaid
Brown      99           210.21
Lyon       73           322.22
Lyon       88           533.22
Lincoln    22           223.21
```

What I am looking for is a query that will return the rows that show the County and the Code for the Max TotalPaid for each County.  An example of the result set that I need is shown below (notice that Lyon, 73 is removed since Lyon, 88 has a higher TotalPaid amount):

```
County     Code         TotalPaid
Brown      99           210.21
Lyon       88           533.22
Lincoln    22           223.21
```

Comment: What database is this?  Oracle, SQL Server, other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to test this, but RANK should solve this:

```
SELECT x.County, x.Code x.TotalPaid
    ,RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY x.County ORDER BY x.TotalPaid DESC) AS 'RANK'
FROM

(SELECT 
   County,
   Code,
   Sum(PaidAmount) AS TotalPaid
FROM
   Counties
GROUP BY
   County,
   Code) x
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like the follwoing.  I've just been called away before I could review what I've written but hopefully it will give you enough of a pointer.  Some RDBMSes won't allow the "where country, TotalPaid = select value, value" construct but you can work around this

```
select 
   County,
   Code,
   TotalPaid
from (SELECT 
       County,
       Code,
       Sum(PaidAmount) AS TotalPaid
     FROM
       Counties
     GROUP BY
       County,
       Code ) tbl
 where County, TotalPaid = (select County, 
                                 max(TotalPaid)
                             FROM
                                 Counties
                             GROUP BY
                                 County,
                                 Code ) tbl2
```

Comment: Don't know about SQL Server, but in Oracle the syntax would be `where (county,totalpaid) IN (select ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT 
   c.County,
   c.Code,
   Sum(c.PaidAmount) AS TotalPaid
   FROM
   Counties c
   WHERE
   c.Code in (select max(c2.code) from counties c2 where c2.county = c.county)
   GROUP BY
   c.County,
   c.Code
```

this one should work although i haven't tested

Comment: He doesn't want the maximum code value, he wants the code that has the maximum `TotalPaid` within each county.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use windowing functions to do this. While what you want is easily expressed in english, it's not easily expressed in SQL, unfortunately. This should do what you need:

```
select
    County, Code, TotalPaid
from
(
SELECT 
   County,
   Code,
   sum(PaidAmount) AS TotalPaid
FROM
   Counties
GROUP BY
   County, Code
) source

where (row_number() over (partition by County order by TotalPaid desc)) = 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's an updated solution:

```
select c1.county, c1.code, c1.paidAmount 
from counties c1
inner join (
  select county, max(paidAmount) paidAmount 
  from counties 
  group by county) c2 
on c1.county=c2.county and c1.paidAmount=c2.paidAmount;
```

Note, if there are multiple max payments for a certain county, this will return all rows that share that maximum.

Comment: That will give me the sum for the Max Code value for each county, which isn't what I want.  I want to Display the County and Code for the rows with the Max TotalPaid.

Comment: @Eric R:  Sorry, realized that just after I posted.  Looking into the best way of doing that...

Comment: @Eric R: Updated my solution.